# conv2d is more accurate or conv1d in image classification?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, machine-learning, django-models

I have executed a program with image classification and it was running good .I was running the code with `conv1D` and `conv2D` . I am getting accuracy  of 0.854 for both `conv1D` and `conv2D`.

Can i know the exact differences between these two things in detail?

Answer (score 1):

Conv1d is a convolution filter of 1 dimension (imagine it like a one dimension array). Conv2d is a filter with 2 dimensions (like a 2d array) and it is more suitable for data like images where it can retain more spatial information in a data point because it is applied to all the neighbors. You can see what is a [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)) to understand why this is better for data like images. For non image data I guess it will not have significant impact whether you use 1d or 2d convolution arrays.

**Note**: Also this site is for programming problems, maybe you should ask your question in [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)